# PHP-Mongodb: How to check the nested array exist or not

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

I am working on backend with mongodb & php. I have stored message content in mongodb database. 
My mongodb database content is this

```
 .......some content.........
    "content": "This is the test message",
    "time_created": 1418813065,
    "status": "read",
    "agencyStatus": "read",
    "reply": [
    {
      "email": "leon@accenture.com",
      "name": "Accenture",
      "content": "Thanks for your test message",
      "time": 1418813145
    }
  ]
```

In my program i am retriving the message content & reply content through foreach loop as is nested as a object inside.

```
<?php echo $mongoMessage['content'];?>
<?php foreach ($mongoMessage['reply'] as $mongoReply){ ?>
<?php echo $mongoReply['content']; ?>
```

My problem is when a record with reply exist i am retriving then it is displaying on browser but a record with no reply, i am retriving then it shows me notice on browser. How to get rid of this situation. This problm i am facing from last week plz help me guys...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I could get you right then you are getting a notice in browser when you try to retrive a document where `reply` array does not have a value.

So to get rid of that you must check first if the `reply` array is not empty. Like this -

```
<?php

echo $mongoMessage['content'];

if (!empty($mongoMessage['reply'])) {

    foreach($mongoMessage['reply'] as $mongoReply)
    { 
        echo $mongoReply['content'];    
    }

}

?>
```

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: you are right. a little mistake i did in the question. the reply element will be there in the database only when the candidate replies to the message & at this moment this array contain reply...but there are other messages which does not have reply element as the candidate didnot replied till.

Comment: Thanks for your comment i got one way to check through. i need to use (isset($mongoMessage['reply'])) in the if statement. That works well now. Thanks for quick reply:-)

Comment: Yes, isset() function is very important. Great that you could find it yourself.